# How to add a theme to GtkSourceView Editor for Anjuta

Tags: themes, gtk, ubuntu-mate, style, anjuta

So I want to use Anjuta and add a Theme. I use the GtkSourceView plugin as my editor. For some reason it doesn't allow me to define colors like with any any other editor but instead requires me to use a gtk theme.

I use Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I'm not sure why but gtksourceview-3.0 and gtksourceview-4 are both installed on my system.

To add a theme I tried a few things. I read someplace that you can make themes with a project called "oomox". I tried that, but it created a massive array of files and directories that didn't seem at all like what GtkSourceView uses, which is a single file. So I scrapped that.

I coped `obsidian.xml` (the closest to what I want my thing to look like) from `/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/styles` and edited it. I placed my new file into `~/.themes`. That didn't work (it doesn't show up in the list when selecting a theme for Anjuta). I tried `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-4/styles` and `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles` and also `~/.local/share/gedit` and `~/.local/share/gedit/styles` (gedit is not installed though).

I am confused how I can add a simple style to this editor and why there isn't any information on that topic. I can imagine people wanting to customize their IDE all the time. Maybe I'm missing something obvious? I searched "adding theme to gtksourceview" and "adding theme to Anjuta". And all I found was how to add a theme to gedit (hence my attempts above) and how to switch the default themes.

Also I don't want to add my theme to the system install directory (`/usr` or `/etc`). Surely there is a way to add it for users (`/home/<user>`) only.

It would be really nice if there were some program I could use to edit my style and give me a preview of some code. (Like most other IDEs). If there is no such thing, then I'd be really nice to at least have a list of all the valid tags.

Edit: Just to test it, I put the new file in with the rest of them in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/styles/` and `3.0` and `2`. Neither soft links nor the file itself seemed to have an effect. I'm very confused. I doublechecked the file itself. All I did was add/delete some color tags and change colors about.

For clarity's sake here is the file.

custom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<style-scheme id="custom" _name="custom" version="1.0">

  <author>MyName</author>
  <_description>Dark color scheme.</_description>

  <color name="green"                       value="#00FF00"/>
  <color name="darkgreen"                   value="#008000"/>
  <color name="red"                         value="#FF0000"/>
  <color name="orange"                      value="#FF8000"/>
  <color name="yellow"                      value="#FF0000"/>
  <color name="blue"                        value="#0000FF"/>
  <color name="lightblue"                   value="#00FFFF"/>
  <color name="purple"                      value="#8080FF"/>
  <color name="gray"                        value="#808080"/>
  <color name="darkgray"                    value="#404040"/>
  <color name="bggray"                      value="#202020"/>
  <color name="purple"                      value="#8080FF"/>
  <color name="white"                       value="#ffffff"/>

  <!-- Global Settings -->
  <style name="text"                        foreground="green"          background="bggray"/>
  <style name="selection"                   foreground="green"          background="gray"/>
  <style name="cursor"                      foreground="white"           background="bggray"/>
  <style name="secondary-cursor"            foreground="darkgray"       background="bggray"/>
  <style name="current-line"                background="gray"/>
  <style name="line-numbers"                foreground="yellow" background="#black"/>
  <style name="draw-spaces"                 foreground="gray"/>
  <style name="background-pattern"          background="bggray"/>

  <!-- Bracket Matching -->
  <style name="bracket-match"               foreground="yellow"/>
  <style name="bracket-mismatch"            foreground="yellow" background="red"/>

  <!-- Right Margin -->
  <style name="right-margin"                foreground="gray" background="bggray"/>

  <!-- Search Matching -->
  <style name="search-match"                background="orange"/>

  <!-- Comments -->
  <style name="def:comment"                 foreground="darkgreen"/>
  <style name="def:shebang"                 foreground="darkgreen" bold="true"/>
  <style name="def:doc-comment-element"     italic="true"/>

  <!-- Constants -->
  <style name="def:constant"                foreground="yellow"/>
  <style name="def:string"                  foreground="yellow"/>
  <style name="def:special-char"            foreground="orange"/>
  <style name="def:special-constant"        foreground="orange"/>
  <style name="def:floating-point"          foreground="purple"/>

  <!-- Identifiers -->
  <style name="def:identifier"              foreground="lightblue"/>

  <!-- Statements -->
  <style name="def:statement"               foreground="green" bold="true"/>

  <!-- Types -->
  <style name="def:type"                    foreground="blue" bold="true"/>

  <!-- Others -->
  <style name="def:preprocessor"            foreground="red"/>
  <style name="def:error"                   foreground="red" background="orange" bold="true"/>
  <style name="def:warning"                 foreground="yellow" background="orange" bold="true"/>
  <style name="def:note"                    foreground="lightblue" background="bggray" bold="true"/>
  <style name="def:underlined"              italic="true" underline="single"/>

  <!-- Heading styles, uncomment to enable -->
  <!--
  <style name="def:heading0"                scale="5.0"/>
  <style name="def:heading1"                scale="2.5"/>
  <style name="def:heading2"                scale="2.0"/>
  <style name="def:heading3"                scale="1.7"/>
  <style name="def:heading4"                scale="1.5"/>
  <style name="def:heading5"                scale="1.3"/>
  <style name="def:heading6"                scale="1.2"/>
  -->

  <!-- Language specific -->
  <style name="diff:added-line"             foreground="darkgreen"/>
  <style name="diff:removed-line"           foreground="red"/>
  <style name="diff:changed-line"           foreground="yellow"/>
  <style name="diff:diff-file"              foreground="green" bold="true"/>
  <style name="diff:location"               foreground="green"/>
  <style name="diff:special-case"           foreground="white" bold="true"/>

  <style name="latex:command"               foreground="green" bold="true"/>
  <style name="latex:include"               use-style="def:preprocessor"/>

</style-scheme>
```

Edit 2:
I found these resources: https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/style-reference.html
But they don't detail which style names are valid. Or where to put the style file.

Comment: Should I migrate to Stackoverflow? Didn't seem like a programming question.